# Google API calendar fetch events calendar wise

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

Is it possible to fetch events from calendar, calendar wise?
As in not to fetch all the events altogether, fetch it calendar wise like the public and personal calendar separately and so on. I am using the Google API package. Is there any inbuilt function to do that? If not, then how should I implement it?

Provide the code in Php. Thanks.

Comment: WElcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Note: we do not provide code we help you fix your code show us what you have tried so far and any errors you are receiving.

Answer (score 1):

The API endpoint you're looking for is [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list). If you're using the API client library for PHP, there's an excellent, **thorough** example implementation to be found on the [Google Calendars API PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php).

That example demonstrates the steps involved:

- Create a new `Google_Client`.
- Use the client to create a new `Google_Service_Calendar` object.
- Then `$service->events->listEvents($calendarId)` will return a collection of `Event` objects (see "Overview" in API ref).

  - $calendarId can be the ID of a calendar (find by using the API to get a `calendarList`) or the string `primary` to get the authenticated user's default calendar events.
  - `listEvents()` accepts an optional second parameter, an array of options that can limit the results by min date, max date, max attendees, etc.